# On what sites are Stack Snippets enabled?

Tags: support, stack-snippets, faq-proposed, site-specific, site-specific-formatting

[Stack Snippets](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) is now a feature on some Stack Exchange sites. On what sites is this feature enabled? Where is it being discussed? And where has it actively been decided not to implement the feature? Also, where can I find the relevant discussion threads?

[Return to FAQ index](/q/7931)

Answer (score 25):

#### Sites where the feature is enabled:

- [Code Golf and Coding Challenges](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2201/do-we-want-stack-snippets)
- [Code Review](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2392/should-we-adopt-stack-snippets-runnable-code-snippets-in-posts)
- [Game Development](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1822)
- Meta Stack Exchange – There was no discussion specifically for Meta.
- [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/6681/should-we-enable-stack-snippets)
- [Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)
- [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2006/habilitar-os-stack-snippets-aqui)
- [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/68/queremos-stack-snippets)
- Stack Overflow на русском
- スタック・オーバーフロー

#### Sites where there is discussion or the implementation is pending:

- [Computer Graphics](https://computergraphics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26)

#### Sites where the feature request has been denied:

- [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1319/79217)
- [GIS](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3771) ([status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred))
- [WordPress](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4043)

---

*Modify this post when the status of a site changes, please link to the relevant discussion post featuring the discussion made before the feature was introduced or denied on a site. Sites where the feature has not been requested are not to be listed in any of the categories.*

Comment: @BillyMailman I don't think this post needs to provide proof explicitly, anyone who question the claim that the feature is enabled on a site can go to that site, click "new question" and check if the editor link shows up. The purpose of the links is to tell us why a site did or did not get the feature.

Comment: @eBusiness Eh, mostly I was trying to keep consistent with other FAQ posts, like the [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) one, where the link is generally made to whatever passes for an official post from the devs that something has changed.

Comment: RU SO has it enabled, but digging up the discussion to enable it has not proven especially fruitful for someone who can't read Cyrillic.