# Can CSS be used in posts?

Tags: support, design, markdown

I was reading that SE allows a number of HTML elements, so I'm wondering if they can also be styled using CSS?

I also noticed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, for entering HTML+CSS+JS snippets. So, it made me further curious about this.

Comment: Beyond some very basic and essential styling (e.g. The width and height of an image), no.

Comment: @angussidney: Isn't that HTML attributes, not CSS at all?

Comment: @NathanTuggy You're right. I just got mixed up with the html attributes and the CSS attributes for width and height.

Answer (score 5):

Besides some basic HTML attributes (full list can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909/)) no styling is allowed (so that rules out CSS).

The options you meaning using HTML / CSS / JS is probably what they call Stack Snippets: a method to put in code for that specific languages that make it runnable on the site without external service. That feature exists only in [few sites in the SE network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239508/152859).